# Puppeteer: find iframe by class

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer with Jest and I'm trying to get the iframe element using this function:

```
const frame = await page
  .frames()
  .find(f => f.name() === 'iframe-class');
```

The problem is: is there a way to get the iframe by his class instead of the name attribute?

I do not have access to this iframe to insert a new attribute, so I need to select by the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [contentFrame](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#elementhandlecontentframe) function.

```js
const elementHandle = await page.$('.iframe-class');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using a document query selector to find your `<iframe class="external-data">`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.external-data');
```